# Receber dados json no PHP

Tags: php, json, python

Estou com dificuldades em receber dados JSON no PHP para salvar no banco de dados, e estes dados são enviados de um *script python*, já tentei o `json_decode` usando a variável `$_REQUEST`, mas sem sucesso, quando eu gravo em um `.txt` eu consigo obter os dados mas quando tento gravar em uma variável para salvar no banco não consigo printar nada para confirmar que os dados foram para variável.

Python

```
import json
import requests
import Adafruit_DHT
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_BMP.BMP085 as BMP085
import time

sensorBMP = BMP085.BMP085();
sensorDHT11 = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11;

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD);
pinoSensorDHT11 = 25;

temperature = 0.0;
pressure = 0.0;
humidity = 0.0;
dia = 0;
hora = 0.0;

while(1):
temperature = sensorBMP.read_temperature();
pressure = sensorBMP.read_pressure();
altitude = sensorBMP.read_altitude();
dia = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y");
hora = time.strftime("%H/%M/%S");
while(1):
humidity, tempNotUsed = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensorDHT11,pinoSensorDHT11);
    if humidity is not None and tempNotUsed is not None:
        dic = {
            'Temperature' : temperature,
            'Humidity' : humidity,
            'Pressure' : pressure,
        }
        jason = json.dumps(dic);
        print(jason);


        r = requests.post("http://54.174.181.91/tcc/jsonTeste.php",   data = {"jsonFile": jason});

        #print (r);
        if r.status_code is not 200:
            print "FALHA!!!!!!";
            print r.status_code;
            break;
    break;
break;
```

E quando gravo em txt usando PHP:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST); 
$data = $_POST["jsonFile"];


// Abre ou cria o arquivo bloco1.txt
// "a" representa que o arquivo é aberto para ser escrito

$fp = fopen("bloco1.txt", "w");

// Escreve "exemplo de escrita" no bloco1.txt
$escreve = fwrite($fp, $data);

// Fecha o arquivo
fclose($fp);


?>
```

Como posso pegar esses dados e gravar em uma variável comum?

Comment: Se `jsonFile` não está presente em `$_POST` o problema é no python que não enviou os valores.

Comment: Mas como ele grava no txt? Porque ele grava no txt mas quando tento trazer pra alguma variável comum não consigo printar na tela, como poderia resolver?

Comment: Quando vc faz `echo $data` aparece o que?

Comment: Então não traz nada :(

Comment: QUando vc exibe o código fonte da página (ctrl+u)  não aparece nada? adicione essas duas linha no início e veja se aparece algum erro, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Ai aparece o seguinte:
     Notice:  Undefined index: jsonFile in /var/www/html/tcc/jsonTeste.php on     line 9

Comment: :D otimooo, um erro, ele diz que `jsonFile` não foi enviado. vc fez `echo $_POST['jsonFile'];` ou `echo $_GET['jsonFile'];`

Comment: Acho que fiz errado, na verdade eu fiz assim:

   
    $data = $_POST["jsonFile"];
    echo "teste" . $data;

Comment: Faz assim e coloca o resultado aqui, `echo '<pre>' print_r($_POST); print_r($_GET);`

Comment: Eu fiz o que vc disse mas ele traz 2 arrays vazios:

Array
(
)
Array
(
)

Comment: em vez de gravar em txt, grave em arquivo.json e use json_encode para um array.

Comment: Acho que você está fazendo os testes na requisição errada. Faça o seguinte:

No Python, após a linha `r = requests.post("htt...` adicione `print r.text`
No PHP, adicione apenas a linha: `print_r(json_decode($_POST['jsonFile'], true));`

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` pega dados de formulários (*headers* do tipo `urlencoded` e `form`).

Você vai conseguir pegar os dados com

`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

lendo o corpo da requisição diretamente.

E por que essa questão apareceu agora na ***home*** do ptSO depois de quase dois anos? OP não conseguiu resolver o problema em dois anos?

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi muito bem a primeira duvida, de você puder mostrar como esta o json que você esta tentando salvar ficaria mais facil.

Mas para sua ultima duvida, quando você salva o json no arquivo, **serializa** o json antes de armazenar, pois você iria gerar um dado serializado e iria conseguir trabalhar melhor na hora de pegar esse json do arquivo, pois quando você le dados de um arquivo você so pode ler linha a linha. Assim você iria pegar uma unica linha que teria todos os seus dados do json, iria dar um **desserializar** e conseguiria colocar em uma unica variável contendo todo o seu json.

Para ler arquivos você pode dar uma olhada na documentação do php.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file.php

Comment: Bom dia Jose, então só que esse txt era para teste para saber se os dados estavam enviando para a página via $_POST, eu não preciso do txt só preciso que os dados sejam gravados direto em uma variável, por exemplo:

a variável 'Temperature' do python ser gravada em uma variável PHP $Temperatura.

Comment: haaa, saquei, bem, pra isso você tem duas formas, ou você terá que criar uma (API, Webservice), para fazer a comunicação entre as duas linguagens que é  mais indicado, ou fazer um post com python, que seria mais complicado.

Comment: Entendi José mas se vc olhar no Python ja estou enviando via post, só que chega no PHP e ele não consegue pegar os dados

Comment: Esse seu projeto vc esta usando arduino? e esta enviando um post para uma pagina web que usa php?

Comment: Fala José, isso mesmo, na verdade é um raspberry.

Comment: Mass, assim, eu não parei pra estudá-lo, mas também vou levantar apenas suposições,  pode ser que o raspberry não esteja enviando um json correto, por conta de uma lib mal feita. 
Eu não me aprofundei muito sobre arduino, mas pode ser que você precise de um shild eternet para fazer a comunicação, eu sei que o eternet envia o cabeçalho http correto como json, mas se o raspberry já faz isso infelizmente não tenho mais possibilidade :(

Comment: Faz uma favor para ajudar na resposta, coloca este código no PHP e coloca aqui o resultado: ```
        ob_start();
        var_dump($_REQUEST);
        var_dump($_SERVER);
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        file_put_contents("data.txt", $content);
        ```

Answer (score -1):

Como você esta usando arduino ele não envia o header da pagina, você pode usar

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

é uma das alternativas, a outra é você definir na hora de salvar no banco o tipo de codificação esta usando, de preferencia UTF8

Answer (score -2):

Tente assim:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonFile);
```